# How to compile Qt 5.2 from git on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, qt, build, dependencies, qt5

I cloned the QT source repo and checked out branch `stable`.

Then I followed this manual http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git until I got to the point I have to do `./configure`:

```
The test for linking against libxcb and support libraries failed!
 You might need to install dependency packages, or pass -qt-xcb.
 See src/plugins/platforms/xcb/README.
```

and when I enter `./configure -qt-xcb`:

```
Running configuration tests...
The test for linking against Xlib failed!
 You might need to install dependency packages.
 See src/plugins/platforms/xcb/README.
```

Now I'm stuck. I couldn't find out what Xlib is, where I can find it or how to install it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why in the would do you want to use X under a Mac?!

Comment: The real question is:  why would Qt feel the need to use XCB on a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

add -no-xcb to configure params

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/).

*Some extra text to get past the filter, please ignore*

Comment: Installed it, even restarted, but I still get the same error :/